# How to Draw circle around current Location like city mapper. (iOS 8 -Objective C)

Tags: ios8, mkmapview, mkcircle

I have a app which tag locations. I have successfully added pins to the Mapview. But i have no idea how to draw circle of radius 100 meters start from my current location and How to make it move with current location.
[iOS 8 Objective-C]
 [Circle like city Mapper App!][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICfEP.jpg)

Comment: Do you know what an annotation is?

Comment: Yes, i have added annotation to MapView.

Comment: matt: if i am guessing right, that means custom circle Annotation for current location.

Comment: You can draw an annotation however you like. The point is: that's how you make a mark on the map that moves with the location and stays in scale with the map. That's what an annotation is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i have managed to create Circle.

```
MKCircle *circleoverlay = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.coordinate radius:100];
[circleoverlay setTitle:@"Circle"];
[mapView addOverlay:circleoverlay];
```

and than Rendering

```
 - (MKOverlayRenderer *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id)overlay
{ if([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKCircle class]])
    {
        MKCircleRenderer* aRenderer = [[MKCircleRenderer
                                        alloc]initWithCircle:(MKCircle *)overlay];

        aRenderer.fillColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0];
        aRenderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9];
        aRenderer.lineWidth = 2;
        aRenderer.lineDashPattern = @[@2, @5];
        aRenderer.alpha = 0.5;

        return aRenderer;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Now i only want to Overlay Text on the circle.
but i dont have any idea :(